# Changing ng-class not updating style?

Tags: css, angularjs

I have following code:

Pug:

```
div(ng-class="('{{selectedMessageType}}' == 'incoming')?'messageTypeSelected':'messageTypeNotSelected'")
```

CSS:

```
.messageTypeSelected{
    background-color: #E8A83C;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.messageTypeNotSelected{
    background-color: #E4E4E4;
}
```

JS:

```
$scope.selectedMessageType = 'incoming';
$scope.changeMessageType = function(){
    ($scope.selectedMessageType ==  'incoming')?$scope.selectedMessageType = 'outgoing':$scope.selectedMessageType = 'incoming';
};
```

My `{{selectedMessageType}}` is replaced correctly with the logic. I have also checked on it using Inspector on browser. However, the styling is not applied, when value is changed.

What could be wrong in my code?

Comment: The syntax for ng-class is an object format. You have to specify class name as key and the value should be a boolean expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `{{}}` in `ngClass` directive.

Change your code to:

```
<div ng-class="selectedMessageType == 'incoming' ? 'messageTypeSelected' : 'messageTypeNotSelected'"></div>
```

A *working* `code`:

```js
(function() {
  angular
    .module('app', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);

  MainCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

  function MainCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.selectedMessageType = 'incoming';
    
    $scope.changeMessageType = function() {
      $scope.selectedMessageType = $scope.selectedMessageType == 'incoming' ? 'outgoing' : 'incoming';
    }
  }
})();
```

```css
.messageTypeSelected {
  background-color: #E8A83C;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.messageTypeNotSelected {
  background-color: #E4E4E4;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-class="selectedMessageType == 'incoming' ? 'messageTypeSelected' : 'messageTypeNotSelected'">
    <span ng-bind="selectedMessageType"></span>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <button type="button" value="change" ng-click="changeMessageType()">Change class</button>
</body>

</html>
```

I'd recommend you to check this [**tutorial**](https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass)

Comment: If I don't put `{{}}`, the `selectedMessageType` won't be replaced with the value. Meanwhile, I am on checking your tutorial.

Comment: Well, let me provide a plunker to show how it works.. Also your statement in javascript should be: `$scope.selectedMessageType = $scope.selectedMessageType == 'incoming' ? 'outgoing' : 'incoming';`

Comment: I mean it could* be in the above comment. Just added a working code.

Comment: Not sure why, from your code, when clicking the button, it will also change the `class` of the div, while mine isn't.

Comment: I just forgot to add the css classes, check it now.

Comment: @Rendy, is it ok now?

Comment: Yes it works! So the culprit is because I add `{{}}` and `''`. Thanks!!

Comment: Pleasure to help :) Check it as answer :D

Answer (score 1):

ngClass does not work the way you wrote it. It takes in the format of:

```
ng-class="{'css-class': trueOrFalseExpression}"
```

the `trueOrFalseExpression` could be `selectedMessageType == 'incoming'`